# How to redirect all outgoing request from my cluster for host "*.mydomain.com" to the ingress IP of the istio installed on the same cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, istio, istio-gateway

I want to redirect all outgoing request from my cluster for host "*.mydomain.com" to the ingress IP of the istio installed on the same cluster.

CAn anybody help me with how that can be done ?

I am trying service entry like this

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: globar-redirects
spec:
  hosts:
  - "ca.bik14name.mycustomer.com"
  location: MESH_INTERNAL
  exportTo:
  - "*"
  ports:
  - number: 443
    name: https
    protocol: TLS
  resolution: STATIC
  endpoints:
  - address: 10.96.237.180
```

And it is not working.
Am I missing something here ?

I tried using coredns and it does what I want. Howver, we need to find a way to achieve this without updating coredns.

Comment: How does your Gateway resource look like? 

You're also missing the `*.mydomain.com` in your `hosts` field.